# Qt QCamera is not working on the Android device

Tags: android, c++, qt

I am working QCamera application on the desktop application but this application is not working on the Android device. Just opening the application. Code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  QCamera* camera = new QCamera(QCamera::BackFace);
  QCameraViewfinder* viewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder(ui->frame);
  camera->setViewfinder(viewfinder);
  camera->start();
}
```

There is a QFrame on the MainWindow. Device: Android 4.4.4 and Qt 5.5.1. Thanks.

Comment: Have you included the fact the application uses the camera in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: No, I did not include camera in the AndroidManifest.xml file. How can I include camera? I found this command: <uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.CAMERA”/> and I included this command in AndroidManifest.xml but it is not running.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: you also need uses-feature